# Word for someone who always questions others

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a single word that describes someone who always questions others? A word to describe how Socrates acts in life or how he questions everyone.

Comment: It could be 'inquisitive' but without context it is difficult to be sure. Please give a sentence with a gap where the word should go. This will give us something to work with. Thanks.

Comment: *Troll* is a single word which fits the description. I'm sure that's not what you had in mind, though. I've found the correct tag for your question: please see the tag info for a checklist of what this sort of question requires.

Comment: In Christian (Catholic, at least) mythology, "Doubting Thomas" is not uncommon. Of course, it's pejorative for Catholics, because it suggests lack of faith; but it also suggests a proper scientific attitude.

Comment: @JohnLawler that sounds like an answer

Comment: Socrates also questioned himself, presumably. Is that part of what you had in mind, or did you mean someone who questions others but rarely puts himself or herself in question?

Comment: *insomniac*, on account of the lack of sleep due to constant questioning

Answer (score 5):

You can describe such a person (and their methods) as *[Socratic](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/socratic)*:

> Of or relating to Socrates, his followers, or his philosophical method
>   of systematic doubt and questioning of another to elicit a clear
>   expression of a truth supposed to be knowable by all rational beings

Comment: Perhaps a "socratic investigator".

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a *[devil's advocate](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/devil's-advocate)*

> A person who expresses a contentious opinion in order to provoke debate or test the strength of the opposing arguments:
>   *the interviewer will need to play devil’s advocate to put the other side’s case forward*

*Oxford Dictionary Online*

Also possibly *[gadfly](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gadfly)*

> a person who stimulates or annoys especially by persistent criticism

*Merriam-Webster*

Answer (score 0):

I would go with [contrarian](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/contrarian), if the person questioning others does so simply to take the opposite view to those around them.

> A person who opposes or rejects popular opinion, especially in stock exchange dealing: 'it has become fashionable to be a stock-market contrarian'

Answer (score 0):

W
The word your looking for is "analytical".

Every human should be analytical if we are going to survive the crap that is being spewed out these days...

Comment: I wonder, does one have to speak to analyse, or is that just cynic if I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Most of these answers are technically correct, they refer to people who ask questions, but the OP was asking about people who follow the Socratic method of questioning everything, and that is A Skeptic.